# Is there a guide available for determining pedal/cleat combinations?

Tags: pedals, cleat, pedals-clipless

I bought a Kona Coiler mountain bike at an estate sale, and the sellers didn't have any information about the pedals on it. I'm looking to buy some shoes and cleats, but I'm not sure what to buy because I haven't been able to identify the proper cleats for the pedal.

When I've ridden mountain bikes in the past, the pedals were the "egg beater" type, which these pedals definitely are not.

If someone can identify the pedal type from the photo, that would be helpful. Even better would be a link to some sort of guide I can use in the future to identify pedals and match them to the appropriate cleat.

Here are the pedals in question (the nickel is there for scale):

[image: pedal]

Comment: Yeah, Shimano "mountain" SPD.  Probably the most popular style for non-racing bikes.  There are several different pedal designs that all use that same cleat, and the shoes fitted for them are mostly interchangeable.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I can tell you there's a problem with your pedal - there's some foreign coin or other in it. You'll need to get it out to be able to use it.

Comment: Just off the top of my head, the other halfway-common styles are the Shimano SPD-SL (much larger cleat, for road bikes), the Look plate pedals, and the Crank Brothers "eggbeaters".

Comment: Speedplay and Time ATAC are the other styles that are common.

Comment: @andy256 hahaha, yes I should have mentioned that I added that for scale purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those look like Shimano mountain SPD [PD-M545](http://www.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/sg/index/products/pedals/mountain/product.-code-PD-M545.html) pedals:

[image]

Looks like a pretty good match to the picture on the Shimano site, but if you don't see a Shimano logo on them, they could be third party compatible pedals.

The cleats look like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano_Pedaling_Dynamics#mediaviewer/File:Shimano_MT31_shoe_with_SH56_cleat-Sole.jpg):

[image]

I'm not aware of a guide that compares all pedal styles, but there are not that many pedal types in common use and most styles are different enough from each other that you can easily tell the difference between them.

Comment: I agree with this answer.  In addition it's worth noting that this "SPD" style of cleats is the most popular one in existence for mountain bikes.  If you go to a shop without the bike and want to be very clear, just tell them you have mountain-style SPD pedals (even if it's a road bike).

Comment: You can just about see the `PD-` number behind the coin so I imagine these are Shimano ones.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Shimano SPD pedal (Shimano PD M-545 maybe?) -- normally these say Shimano on them somewhere in the cleat area, so look for a marking on them.

You can take the bike to the shop with you when you go to try cycling shoes (which you'll have to try in person) since they size in stupid ways. Then you'll easily be able to verify that its a SPD cleat.